# React Native - JSON local storage

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, local-storage

I'm trying to fetch data from a JSON file. I want this file to be in the application, so no fetch on a server, local storage only.

How do I do that?

I search on the internet, and it's either fetch on a server, or add data to AsyncStorage (or similar).

If I were in python, I would simply do this :

```
import json

data = json.load(open('data.json'))
```

Then I could use the data as I see fit.

Thanks in advance.

Note : I have the file in JSON, but I could change it to any format that is supported by python (my script for parsing and generating the data is in python).

Comment: Simply import your `json` file like `const data = require("./data.json")` or `import data from "./data.json"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply import your json file like const data = require("./data.json") or import data from "./data.json" – @Tuấn Trần Duy